# .on('mouseenter'... not detecting appended element (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

The below code is not binding the event to an appended element (using `.insertBefore()`).

From my understanding, `.on()` is supposed to work like `.live()`. Is this not the case?

```
<div class="todoColumn">
    <div class="projectHeader">
        <div class="title">Example</div>Subtitle
    </div>

    <div class="todo">
        <div class="checkbox"><span class="check pictos">3</span></div>

        <div class="text">another test</div>

        <div class="floatfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="todo">
        <div class="checkbox"><span class="check pictos">3</span></div>

        <div class="text">another test</div>

        <div class="floatfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
    $('.todoColumn .todo .checkbox').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find('.check').css('visibility','visible');
    });
```

Comment: In addition to the `.on()` issue discussed in the answers, your selector `'.column .todo .checkbox'` is wrong.  You don't have a `.column`.  You have a `.todoColumn` so it would have been `'.todoColumn .todo .checkbox'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon where you put the selector.  Putting it in the first jQuery object does not have any `.live()` behavior.  It binds static event handlers.

Specifying a comment parent object in the jQuery object and putting the selector in the arguments to `.on()` gives you live behavior:

```
$(document.body).on('mouseenter', '.todoColumn .todo .checkbox', function() {
    $(this).find('.check').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

It will work even more efficiently (and better than `.live()`) if you pick a common parent that is closer to the actual objects than document.body.  A problem with `.live()` was too many event handlers (all with selectors to check) on the document object.  .on() works more like `.delegate()` and allows you to put the event handler on a common parent that is closer to the actual objects.

EDIT: Now that you've included your HTML, more efficient code would be this with a common parent selector in the jQuery object and the simplest possible selector in the `.on()` arguments:

```
$('.todoColumn').on('mouseenter', '.checkbox', function() {
    $(this).find('.check').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Comment: Similar to @Purmou 's solution, the contextual selector `'.column .todo .checkbox'` isn't working, but I was able to make it work by feeding it a simpler selector `'.checkbox'`.

Comment: @DesignerGuy - `.on()` does work with contextual selectors.  You'd have to show us your actual HTML, including the code that does the appending for us to make further suggestions on what is the appropriate selector - we were just copying what you included in your question.

Comment: just added HTML elements above

Comment: Nevermind. Just made it work. Thanks! Please +1 my question if you think it will be helpful to someone else in the future :)

Comment: I've added to the end of my answer based on your actual HTML.

Answer (score 2):

To use it the way you want, you need to place the selector in the function and bind the event to the document:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".column .todo .checkbox", function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

And, like jfriend00 suggested, it's more efficient to bind the event to the closest parent:

```
$(".column .todo").on("mouseenter", ".checkbox", function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: Are you including the latest jQuery? The `on()` function was added in 1.7.

Comment: Yup. The `.on()` method was working, just not adding for the appended item.

Comment: Are you sure the appended item has the proper class? You're selecting the `checkbox` class, so make sure that it's getting that class added when it's being appended.

Comment: Just made this work: `$(document.body).on('mouseenter', '.checkbox', function() {` - must not work with contextual selectors

Comment: In that case just bind the `on()` to `.column .todo`. It will be more efficient. See my edit.

Comment: Tried that, but for some reason it isn't working either. I can only get the `document.body` selector in combination with the `.checkbox` selector to work.

Comment: Just got it working. Thanks for your help! Please +1 my question if you think it will be helpful to someone else in the future :)